# How to `HAVING` on `SUM` without "Non-grouping field x is used in HAVING clause"

Tags: sql, grouping, mariadb, having

So, I have this query, which runs fine in HeidiSQL, but not in Laravel because of strict mode (and more specifically probably because of the SQL mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` being set):

```
SELECT
    project.id
        'Project code',
    SUM(report.hours)
        'Total hours',
    SUM(CASE WHEN report.date BETWEEN :report_start AND :report_end THEN report.hours END)
        'Total report hours'

FROM report
    INNER JOIN project ON project.id = report.id
WHERE report.date <= :report_end

GROUP BY
    project.id

HAVING
    `Total report hours` != 0
```

It gives me the following error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'Total report hours' is used in HAVING clause

I've tried searching around here, but all questions I find are solved by moving the filter from `HAVING` to `WHERE`, which can be done because those cases don't actually include an aggregate function. However, in my case, it does, and I thought this was exactly what `HAVING` was for? I.e. I want to filter out all rows that do not have any hours in the reported period.

I can "solve" it by instead of referring to `Total report hours`, instead repeating the whole `SUM`, like this:

```
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN report.date BETWEEN :report_start AND :report_end THEN report.hours END) != 0
```

But that feels very unnecessary and messy when it's already calculated and (from my point of view) available right there in the query itself.

So, is there a way I can express this, that works in strict mode, without *having* to repeat myself?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Smells like a bug to report at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: @RickJames MariaDB 10.2 I believe (but unable to check for sure until I'm at work tomorrow )

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which version of MySQL MariaDB 10.2 is based on, but at least in MySQL, this was a bug. It has been fixed in MySQL 5.7.5.

- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=51058
- http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-only_full_group_by-improved-recognizing-functional-dependencies-enabled-by-default/

The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) even mentions this:

> As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

In some databases, you need to copy the aggregation expression:

```
SELECT p.id as 'Project code',
       SUM(r.hours) as 'Total hours',
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.date BETWEEN :report_start AND :report_end THEN r.hours END) as 'Total report hours'
FROM report r INNER JOIN
     project p
     ON p.id = r.id
WHERE r.date <= :report_end
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.date BETWEEN :report_start AND :report_end THEN r.hours END) <> 0;
```

I would advise you to not use single quotes for column aliases.  You are using multiple databases, so it is unclear which escape character is best -- backticks, double quotes, or square braces.

Of course, you can also use a subquery.

Comment: Yeah, copying the the aggregation expression is what I did as a workaround. Works, but messy.  What do you mean about not using single quotes though? What should one use?

Comment: @Svish . . . In MariaDB, use backticks.

Comment: Why though? Like, what can happen if one doesn't?

Comment: @Svish . . . One day, you will make a mistake and refer to the column using single quote.  Then, you'll spend lots of time debugging a query, because you have really put in a string constant.

Comment: @Svish: The MySQL manual has an example of the problem at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html: `SELECT id AS 'a', COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name GROUP BY 'a';`. - The query does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query up in a derived table. Add the condition at top level:

```
select *
from
(
SELECT
    project.id
        'Project code',
    SUM(report.hours)
        'Total hours',
    SUM(CASE WHEN report.date BETWEEN :report_start AND :report_end THEN report.hours END)
        'Total report hours'

FROM report
    INNER JOIN project ON project.id = report.id
WHERE report.date <= :report_end

GROUP BY
    project.id
) dt
WHERE `Total report hours` != 0
```

Comment: Hm... when I do this, I actually get the same error, *Non-grouping field 'Total report hours' is used in HAVING clause*... even though there aren't even any `HAVING` clause in the actual query run... 

Comment: Looks like a bug.